# Selection of suitable Newton Interpolation for equispaced points

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

We have studied in Numerical analysis book two types of Newton interpolation for equispaced points. It was also taught that we should use the forward one for the points closer to the initial point and the backward one for the points closer to the end point, once the points are arranged in order.

But I could not find any proper reason for the above selection. Some people say it is all about finite arithmetic that plays the role despite the interpolating polynomials are theoretically same for both the cases.

Please suggest me some suitable reading that can clarify my doubt.

Comment: Does this topic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624894/newtons-interpolation-formula-difference-between-the-forward-and-the-backward demonstrate and answer your question?

Comment: Not well explained.