# Difference between newton forward and backward

Tags: numerical-methods

Newton forward difference method is better for points which are closer to x0, while Newton backward difference method is better for points which are closer to xn. I dont want any example. I want formal logic.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4106126/selection-of-suitable-newton-interpolation-for-equispaced-points?

Comment: Yes this is the same question